# Owin FileServer Configuration

Tags: owin

I'm trying to put together an OWIN configuration that allows me to serve static files from a directory in my project. I'm also starting pretty much from scratch (from a blank WebAPI project in Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1). Here is what I have so far:

```
var options = new FileServerOptions
            {
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
                EnableDefaultFiles = true,
                DefaultFilesOptions = { DefaultFileNames = { "index.html" } },
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\StaticFiles"),
                StaticFileOptions = {
                    ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { ".html", "text/html" }
                    })
                }
            };
            app.UseFileServer(options);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I can browse the directory StaticFiles from the root url (as I would expect) but as soon as I click on a file (Login.html at this point) I get a 404 with the message "The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.".

To note: The login.html file is included in the build (copy newer), and I have disabled IIS file serving, using the handlers option:

```
<remove name="StaticFile" />
```

I am at a loss for where to go from here, obviously I'm missing something. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to tell IIS to pass all requests through OWIN:

```
<add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>
```

That needed to go in the handlers section.

If anyone has a better/different solution for this, I would still like to hear it.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your configuration. Somehow, once I add that line, the Startup file gets called multiple times. Any thoughts ?